# Why am I not entering this for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Why am I not entering this for loop?
Looks like the for loop isn't processing

```js
let z = [1, 2];

function filter_list(l, z) {
  // Why am I not entering the for loop? 
  let del = [];
  for (let i = 0; l.length < i, i++;) {
    if (z[i] === l[i]) {
      console.log(l)
    } else {
      l[i].push(del)
      console.log(l);
    }
  }
  del = undefined
  delete(del);
}

let l = [1, 2, 'a', 'b'];
filter_list(l);
```

Comment: `l.length < i`. Try flipping those around.  Eg. `i < l.length`

Comment: 1) The condition should be `i < l.length` 2) In `for` you need to use `;` instead of `,` 3) You are also not passing the `z` parameter to the function. 4) What is `del = undefined; delete(del)`?

Answer (score 0):

missing semicolon after condition. You have a comma instead.You also have an extra semicolon after incrementation. Also you have the condition flipped like CherryDT stated

change this `for(let i = 0; l.length < i, i++;){`
to this `for(let i = 0; i<l.length; i++){`

Comment: let z = [1,2];
function filter_list(l) {
  // Why am I not entering the for loop? 
  for(let i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
    if(z[i] === l[i]){

      } 
    else {
      del = [];
      del.push(l[i]);
      console.log(l[i]);
      }
    }
    del = undefined
    delete(del);  }
  
  let l = [1,2,'a','b'];
  filter_list(l);

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in the code that you posted - the order of arguments in the for loop, syntax, passing of variables, etc. I have attempted to explain below.

```
// note that this function takes two arguments "l" and "z" so they will be limited to the function scope
function filter_list(l, z) {
  // this is never being used?
  let del = [];
  // Why am I not entering the for loop? 
  // check for i less than l.length
  // separate using a semicolon
  // prefer using i+=1
  for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i+=1) {
    if (z[i] === l[i]) {
      // this will happen if the same element is in the same position in each array, you probably want to not specify the index?
      console.log(l)
    } else {
      // del is an empty array here, it will just overwrite the index of l
      l[i].push(del)
      console.log(l);
    }
  }
  // this is probably not needed
  del = undefined
  // this function is not defined and does nothing since del=undefined
  delete(del);
}

// you need to pass two arguments to filter_list(), using different variable names to clarify
let one = [1, 2, 'a', 'b'];
let two = [1, 2];
filter_list(one, two);
```

If you want to filter one list by another a better way to do it would be to use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
const one = [1, 2, 'a', 'b'];
const two = [1, 2];

const three = one.filter((element) => two.includes(element);
```